# How to show brakelines in asp.net textbox multiline?

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I have a Textbox with Multiline enabled.
but i can get the line brakes when i press the enter button,
any idea on how to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you debug what is posted by multiline textbox you can see the value is like that :

> line 1.**\r\n**line 2.

so if you assign multiline textbox's text property like that you can set your text with breaks :

```
txtMulti.Text = "line 1.\r\nline 2.";
```